# Querying for clicks by link

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am sending out newsletters that I have advertisements in them and I need to be able to pull a list for each advertiser when their link has been clicked identifying those who have clicked. I am sending newsletters a few times a week so it would be easiest if all the links for one advertiser can be hosted in one list. How would I go about doing this? Currently I have a query that is created that jumbles all of the clicks together and I have to manually go through and separate them.

Comment: I recommend editing your question title to something like "Querying for clicks by link" in order to make it more easily found by other users, since the question is not specific to your links' business purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The _Click data view contains fields **URL** and **LinkName** that can be used to break down engagement by link.

Example:

```
SELECT 
URL
, count(*) as [Clicks] 
from _Click with (nolock) 
where JobID = 1234
```

Reference:

- [**Click Data View**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_click/)